# Error resolving template JSP program is trying to use Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, jsp, thymeleaf

I am using the Spring MVC I have some issues when I am trying to execute my chart code.
Precisely in my project are templates in html format but now I am obliged to use .jsp extension.

My error :

```
2019-06-19 14:51:48.364 ERROR 14784 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "Chart.jsp", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "Chart.jsp", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

The most important code :

```
<!-- chart.jsp-->
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

var dps = [[]];
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    exportEnabled: true,
    title: {
        text: "Simple Column Chart with Index Labels"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "column", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
        //indexLabel: "{y}", //Shows y value on all Data Points
        indexLabelFontColor: "#5A5757",
        dataPoints: dps[0]
    }]
});

var xValue;
var yValue;
var indexLabel;

<c:forEach items="${dataPointsList}" var="dataPoints" varStatus="loop">
    <c:forEach items="${dataPoints}" var="dataPoint">
        xValue = parseInt("${dataPoint.x}");
        yValue = parseFloat("${dataPoint.y}");
        indexLabel = "${dataPoint.indexLabel}";
        dps[parseInt("${loop.index}")].push({
            x : xValue,
            y : yValue,
            indexLabel : indexLabel
        });
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>

chart.render();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
    <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/canvasjschart")
public class CanvasjsChartController {

    @Autowired
    private CanvasjsChartService canvasjsChartService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String springMVC(ModelMap modelMap) {
        List<List<Map<Object, Object>>> canvasjsDataList = canvasjsChartService.getCanvasjsChartData();
        modelMap.addAttribute("dataPointsList", canvasjsDataList);
        return "Chart.jsp";
    }

}
```

I'd like to add that other templates use thymeleaf. In this case I also can rewrite this into HTML, but I don't now how.

Project structure :

[image]

Comment: Why would you need a JSP for this? You can achieve the same with a thymeleaf page.

Comment: Can You show me how ?